# Solving $\frac{d^2 z}{dr^2}=\left(\frac{1}{c(r,z)}\ \frac{\partial c(r,z)}{\partial z}\right)\cdot\left[1+\left(\frac{dz}{dr}\right)^2\right]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following differential equation
$$\frac{d^2 z}{dr^2}=\left(\frac{1}{c(r,z)}\ \frac{\partial c(r,z)}{\partial z}\right)\cdot\left[1+\left(\frac{dz}{dr}\right)^2\right]$$
where $c$ is a generic function of $z$, $r\in\mathbb R$.My approach:
$$m(r):=\frac{dz}{dr}\Rightarrow \ \frac{m'(r)}{m^2(r)+1}= \frac{1}{c(r,z)}\ \frac{\partial c(r,z)}{\partial z}$$
but the situation does not improve.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: It might help to consider that $$\frac{1}{c(r,z)}\ \frac{\partial c(r,z)}{\partial z} = \frac{\partial \ln c(r,z)}{\partial z}$$.

Comment: $$\arctan m(r) = \int \frac{\partial\ln c(r, z)}{\partial z}dr$$